# definition utomorphism of order $2$

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

An automorphism of a graph is a graph isomorphism with itself, i.e., a mapping from the vertices of the given graph  $G$ back to vertices of $G$such that the resulting graph is isomorphic with $G$
i need definition utomorphism of order $2$.
can you help me?

Comment: Are you familiar with the basics of group theory?

Answer (score 1):

An automorphism of order $2$ is simply an automorphism $\phi \ne id$  such that $\phi \circ \phi = id$, that is, a nontrivial automorphism that is its own inverse.